# Open a new browser tab without losing focus on current application using C++

Tags: c++, windows, url, browser, dll

I would like to open a new browser tab using C++ on Windows, ideally browser-independent, if that is not possible chrome is good enough.

But there are some restrictions:

- The current application can not lose focus, but the browser must switch to the new tab.
- The tab must be opened to a specific URL
- The tab must be opened from a 3rd party application, so not from inside the browser.

I have tried using `system("start <url>")` but that causes the application focus to switch to the browser. I could not find a `chrome://` URL to open a new tab with an initial URL.
I have also found several threads showing similar things in JavaScript, but none for C++.

**Is there a way** *(ideally safer than using `system()`)* **to open a new browser tab without losing focus on the current application, using C++ on windows?**

*Additional clarification:*

3 windows open: One game, the browser and a 3rd party application.
The game is in the foreground, but the 3rd party application opens the browser tab on certain events. Sadly, this means that DLL injection is not an option, due to several anti-cheat restrictions. This also means that a background application needs to open a new browser tab of a browser that is also in the background *without* ever losing focus on the game.

Comment: Does this solves your problem https://superuser.com/questions/18383/preventing-applications-from-stealing-focus ?

Comment: Sadly not, I updated the question to clarify why.